# Is this question a good fit?

Tags: discussion, scope

I know I asked 2 bad quality questions on this site and I'd like to prevent that from happening again by asking here,on meta,before posting a new one.

> My question is about codeblocks and the working of projects.It's a
>   while since it broke and any project I create or open will not allow
>   me to open the main executable.I have to chase the main executable in
>   the folders and click on it in order to start writing code.
>
> Sometimes,not even this will work and it will give me errors like
>   "can't find time stamp".I uninstalled codeblocks and then I installed
>   it again.The problem persists.You may say"Perhaps the old projects
>   were problematic.Have you tried creating new ones?".Yes,I have.It's
>   all the same.
>
> I searched on the internet,but found nothing useful.I could try
>   changing some setting,but the amount of options listed confuses me.I
>   suspect that it started misbehaving since I used winmm as a link
>   library.How do I solve this problem?

Do you think this question is ok for the main?

Comment: I'm afraid that will be a duplicate. I've seen many questions about this situation.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Can you point me to one of the duplicates please?

Comment: Sounds a bit broad for right now.  If you provide more detail (or even edit the proposed question into this meta post), we can give more specific feedback.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I edited

Comment: SO is not a replacement for the internet; this reads more like a tech support question, not a question that can be factually answered in its current state. I would try to post here: http://forums.codeblocks.org ; it has a help subforum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely to be well received on SO. Based on description problem can't be reproduced and essentially you are looking for long list of troubleshooting steps. Closed as "Too broad" or "consider SuperUser" are likely outcomes.

Usually broadly used tools / IDEs have they own forums / support channels to discuss such "tool does not work sometimes. Help" issues.

If you still want to try at very least remove "searched on the internet" sentence and replace with concrete things you've found and tried. Even if it will not make question completely on-topic it demonstrates that you actually tried to solve it. "Searched on the internet" is completely useless statement - maybe you've searched for "cheap flights" or "cute cats"? Also organize post by clearly explaining problem you observe, step you've tried to fix, consider to mention recommendations you've found and skipped.